# How should I write destructor in this code

Tags: c++

Im learning linked list and using dynamic memory allocation but i dont understand how to write destructor because there are methods which are using new and out of scope for destructor method. By the way Node is basically a  class with 2 private members, one int and one pointer to itself(Node).

```
List::List()
{
HeadNode = new Node();
HeadNode->SetNext(nullptr);
CurrentNode = nullptr;
LastCurrentNode = nullptr;
Size = 0;
}

void List::Add(int AddObject)
{
Node* NewNode = new Node();
NewNode->Set(AddObject);
if (CurrentNode != nullptr)
{
    NewNode->SetNext(CurrentNode->GetNext());
    CurrentNode->SetNext(NewNode);
    LastCurrentNode = CurrentNode;
    CurrentNode = NewNode;
}
else
{
    NewNode->SetNext(nullptr);
    HeadNode->SetNext(NewNode);
    LastCurrentNode = HeadNode;
    CurrentNode = NewNode;
}
Size++;
}

int List::Get()
{
if (CurrentNode != nullptr)
{
    return CurrentNode->Get();
}
}

bool List::Next()
{
if (CurrentNode == nullptr)
{
    return false;
}
LastCurrentNode = CurrentNode;
CurrentNode = CurrentNode->GetNext();
if ((CurrentNode == nullptr) || (Size = 0))
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
}

void List::Remove()
{
if (CurrentNode != nullptr && CurrentNode != HeadNode)
{
    LastCurrentNode->SetNext(CurrentNode->GetNext());
    delete CurrentNode;
    CurrentNode = LastCurrentNode->GetNext();
    Size--;
}
}
```

Comment: *There are methods which are using new and out of scope for destructor method* -- Write a function to delete all the nodes.  Stick a `List::~List()` in front of it.  That's the destructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destructor should delete all nodes, and you can use `Remove()` to do that.

```
List::~List() {
    while (Size > 0) {
        Remove(CurrentNode);
    }
    delete HeadNode;
}
```

Also you have a bug in `Next()`, I think you mean `Size == 0`.